# Image does not fill contaning element

Tags: html, css

I have a design where the page is split into two parts where the left side contains an image and the right side some text.

The problem is that the image does not fill the left side.

Usually I can solve this problem by adding display "block" to the image but this time it doesn't help.

Here you can see the code of the page:
https://codepen.io/Lavonen/pen/vbOqdd

```
<!-- Left side -->  
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff;">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://oncokdm.com/assets/barre.png" width="75%" height="auto" />
            <img src="https://images.drivereasy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_5b19100729335.jpg" width="75%" height="auto" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Right side -->     
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff; text-align: left;">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="head">blablalba blablabla blablalba</div>
            <div class="subh">blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .column 
{
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.column .image
{
    margin-top: 22vh;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column .content 
{
    margin: 40vh 10vw 0 0;
}

.row:after 
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.column .content .head 
{
    margin: 25px 0 30px 0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.column .content .head:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;

    width: 40px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #004c71;
}

.column .content .subh 
{
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #a8a8a8;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
    #section3 .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here is an image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly because, you have `width="75%"`, which limits it. Make it `width="100%"`.

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://oncokdm.com/assets/barre.png" width="100%" height="auto" />
    <img src="https://images.drivereasy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_5b19100729335.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" />
</div>
```

Doing that looks this way:

[image: preview]

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGJMwN

The other method is to give border to the image, but you need to deal with floats and layout, so I feel the above solution is better.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code and I also fixed image bottom issue which is showing on other posts.

```css
.column 
{
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

.column .image {
    margin-top: 22vh;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
}
.column .content 
{
    margin: 40vh 10vw 0 0;
}

.row:after 
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.column .content .head 
{
    margin: 25px 0 30px 0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.column .content .head:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;

    width: 40px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #004c71;
}

.column .content .subh 
{
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #a8a8a8;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.image img {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
    #section3 .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Left side -->  
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff;">
      <div class="image">
          <img src="http://oncokdm.com/assets/barre.png" height="auto" />
          <img src="https://images.drivereasy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_5b19100729335.jpg" height="auto" />
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Right side -->     
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff; text-align: left;">
      <div class="content">
          <div class="head">blablalba blablabla blablalba</div>
          <div class="subh">blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba blablalba blablabla blablalba</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```